# Powershell: c# compiler path

Tags: c#, powershell

In powershell it is is possible to compile/run a c# code, or add classes by using `Add-Type`. As far as I know it is necessary to have a compiler in order to generate binary (.dll) files. Where does powershell take this compiler from? is it included somewhere in windows or is it a component of powershell?

Comment: C# compiler up to 5.0 is a part of .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's built into the .Net framework:

```
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\{version}\csc.exe
```

e.g.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>csc /?
Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2005 Compiler version 8.00.50727.8007
for Microsoft (R) Windows (R) 2005 Framework version 2.0.50727
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2001-2005. All rights reserved.

                      Visual C# 2005 Compiler Options
```